# contextstoppedevent vs contextclosedevent in spring?

Tags: java, spring, event-handling

Can any one please explain me what is the difference between the contextstoppedevent vs contextclosedevent in spring .

I think they are same like ,

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext sss = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) ((ApplicationContextEvent) event).getApplicationContext();
sss.stop();
sss.close();
```

May I know where I have to use and when I have to use it ?

Answer (score 11):

First of all, in the vast majority of cases, it's not you who has to explicitly call the `stop()` and `close()` methods. Usually, they will be called by the framework and you will listen for the associated events.

You can find [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/event_handling_in_spring.htm) a good comparison of events related to Spring lifecycle. Essentially, closing event occurs chronologically after any other stop events. A stopped context can be restarted, but a closed one cannot be reopened.